# How to keep Sencha Ext.Msg from closing on button click

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, sencha-touch

So i Have a Message box I built to be able to send a message. It has 2 inputs, and an OK and Cancel buttons. I can access the contents and do the normal logic quite easily how I set it up:

```
Ext.Msg.show({
        title: 'Send a Message: ',
        cls: 'MessageBox',
        html: '<div class="message-InnerContainer" >' +
            '<input type="text" id="messageBoxSubject" placeholder="Subject" class="messageBox-Input"/>' +
            '<textarea id="messageBoxMessage" placeholder="Message" class="messageBox-TextArea"></textarea>' +
            '<div>',
        closable: false,
        buttons: [
            { no: 'Cancel', text:'Cancel', cls:'messageBox-CancelButton'},
            { yes: 'OK', text:'Ok', cls:'messageBox-OkButton'}
        ],
        fn: function (btn) {
            if (btn == 'ok') {
                //do success logic
            }
            else (){
                //do failure logic
            }
        }
    });
```

There is only one problem: I can't seem to find a way to keep the box from auto closing when OK is pressed. Ideally I would like to run a quick check to ensure that the two inputs are not empty. I think I might just be able to override buttons by placing custom buttons in the html section, but if there is a way to halt the auto closing it would be more syntactically pleasing and readable. Does anyone know if its possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh my! You should really consider using some regular Ext [text field](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Text) and [text area](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#) as [items](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Container-cfg-items) of the window instead of your own baked html...

Anyway, use the [`handler`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Button-cfg-handler) of your buttons, instead of the `fn` handler. You'll be able to do whatever you want in there, and close the window only if you feel like it:

```
buttons: [
    { text:'Cancel', cls:'messageBox-CancelButton', handler: function() {
        this.hide();
    }},
    { text:'Ok', cls:'messageBox-OkButton', handler: function() {
        var allGood = false;

        // do your stuff here

        // ... and if your satisfied with the result, close the window
        if (allGood) {
            this.hide();
        }
    }}
]
```

Comment: As a afterthought, if you really like messing with HTML, I believe JQuery Mobile would be more suited to your style.